# I can't listen for Value Changes on a reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, frontend, observable

I encountered the following error when trying to listen for value changes on a reactive form:

> This expression is not callable. Type 'Observable<string | null>' has no call signatures.

```
wordToSearch = this.fb.group({
  word: ['']
});

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.wordToSearch.get('word')!.valueChanges()
}
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Screenshot is not a question

Answer (score 8):

You need to subscribe valueChanges, it is not a function it is a observable.

```
this.wordToSearch.get('word').valueChanges.subscribe((w)=>{
  console.log(w);
});
```

hope this will solve your issue!!

Comment: Also, remember to unsubscribe from these changes to avoid memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

A follow-up to the above answer which is correct: `valueChanges` acts as a Subject, meaning it needs a value to change in order to trigger.

If you want it to immediately trigger (ex. when using with `combineLatest`), it would be written like this:

```
this.wordToSearch.get('word').valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(this.wordToSearch.get('word').value)
)
```

Or you can enter any value you want instead of using the form value itself:

```
this.wordToSearch.get('word').valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith('')
)
```